# Парсинг XML (CommerceML) в php

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Доброго времени.
Проблема такая. Имею файл на основе `CommerceML` (`XML`), который может иметь неограниченный уровень вложенности групп.
Пытаюсь распарсить его на PHP с помощью `SimpleXML`, но до неограниченного парсинга мне еще далеко.  
Знаю, что существуют такие заумные вещи, как `SimpleXMLIterator`, а за ним `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, которые помогут определять, есть ли у родительского элемента дети, и так до самого конца, с помощью рекурсии.
Google старался помочь, но у меня так и не вышло.
Я не прошу сделать работу за меня, я прошу, может у кого-нибудь есть примеры реализации парсинга массивов/`XML` с помощью данных способов, обеспечивающих возможность парсинга неограниченного количества вложенностей категорий?

Comment: Приложи пример XML и что тебе надо на выходе

Comment: А в чём проблема с SimpleXML?

Answer (score 1):

Для сложных XML файлов с широкими требованиями к выборке, лучше использовать XPath https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: Парсим xml википедией...

Comment: Евгений Ваганыч, вы ли это? Человек просил просто указать курс - я указал.

Comment: Просили _пример_ парсинга, а не описание xpath. По ссылке даже названия классов, которые понадобятся для поиска нет. Это во-первых. А во-вторых, парсинг тут скорее всего подразумевает извлечение всех данных, а не какого-то конкретного поля. В этом варианте xpath бесполезен.

Comment: Вы не компетентны в этом вопросе, однозначно, если считаете, что XPath нужен для выбора "конкретного поля". "Я не прошу сделать работу за меня" - я её и не делаю. Я дал вектор.

Comment: Xpath нужен ещё для преобразования. Но преобразование из xml во что-то, что будет обрабатываться в том же коде бессмысленно. Остаётся поиск узлов. Есть некоторая вероятность, что это то, что нужно, но скорее всего, всё-таки нет.